# jQuery equivalent of my javascript code (function value passing to a form)

Tags: javascript, jquery, forms

Just want to ask what is the equivalent of my JavaScript code in jQuery.
by the way, $name & $age came from my PHP code. I wanted to know how to pass the ($name and $age) value using jQuery to my form.
Here's my code below:

```
<input type="button" name="edit" value="edit" onclick="show('$name','$age')";>

<script>
function show(name,age)
{
getElementById("#hidden_division").visibility="visible";
getElementById("#name_input").value=name;
getElementbyId("#age_input").value=age;
}
 </script>

<div id="hidden_division>
<form action="somewhere.php">
<input type="text" name="name_form" id="name_input">
<input type="text" name="age_form" id="age_input">
<input type="submit" value="submit">
</form>
<div>
```

Comment: I think you meant to omit the `#` from your selectors. `getElementById()` does not take CSS selector syntax.

Comment: why using jquery for this kind of simple task?

Comment: Are you having a specific problem converting it to jQuery?

Comment: Ok here's my real problem.    My button (<input name="edit">) at my sample code at the top is coming from each row of my php table. So each row has a button(depends on my sql data) lets just say echo "<tr><td>".$name."</td><td>.$age."</td><td><input name='edit' value="edit" onclick="show('$name','$age')";></td></tr>. just ignore my syntax here.

Comment: So everytime i click the button the $name,$age will automatically populate(fill) my hidden form. Later on those value to insert to my sql table using ajax.. I was planning to use jquery modal form that is why i was asking what is the equivalent to jquery.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't understand why you would need jQuery for that (it's slower and not even much shorter), but this is what it would look like:

In the html:

```
<input type="button" id="editbutton" value="edit">
```

In the script (after jQuery is loaded):

```
jQuery(function($) {
    $("#editbutton").click(function(e) {
        show('$name','$age');
    });
});

function show(name,age) {
    // If you meant the .style property, use the .css() method instead of .prop()
    $("#hidden_division").prop("visibility", "visible");
    $("#name_input").val(name);
    $("#age_input").val(age);
}
```

Comment: LEt me clarify my problem. I have a table created based from the value from my sql database. Lets just say i have 3 columns name,age,and an edit button. and say 10 rows. So each row has different value of name and age. so when i click the button in my table. I want its value(name,age) to automaticaly fill in my hidden form and later on I will use ajax to submit it again to my database. My sample at the top works fine,, but i was planning to use jquery modal form that is why im asking what is the equivalent

Comment: Let me try when i get back to office tommorow. thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I think if I understand you correctly, you are asking how to pass $name and $page to your function using jQuery?

This is pretty simple, once you include jQuery.

```
$("#submit_button").live("click", function(){
    var name = $("#name_input").val();
    var age  = $("#age_input").val();
    show(name, age);
});
```

Comment: Yes, thats what a want. LEt me clarify my problem. I have a table created based from the value from my sql database. Lets just say i have 3 columns name,age,and an edit button. and say 10 rows. So each row has different value of name and age. so when i click the button in my table. I want its value(name,age) to automaticaly fill in my hidden form and later on I will use ajax to submit it again to my database. My sample at the top works fine,, but i was planning to use jquery modal form that is why im asking what is the equivalent

Comment: Let me try when i get back to office tommorow. thanks.